# phpmailer AUTH not accepted from server

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to send an email using phpmailer, it works fine when I send to gmail but stops for any other(hotmail,yahoo ... ) ,it keeps giving me (AUTH not accepted from server) for smtp debug and (Language string failed to load: from_failedorder@toheco.com) for $email->error info

here is my code :

```
require_once("./PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php");
 $email = new PHPMailer();
$email->IsSMTP();
$email->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$email->SMTPAuth = true;
$email->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$email-> Port = 465;
//$email->SetLanguage( 'en', './PHPMailer-master/language/' );
$email->Username   = "username";
$email->Password   = "*******";
$email->SMTPDebug  = 2;
$email->From      = 'order@toheco.com';
$email->FromName  = 'order@toheco.com';
$email->Subject   = 'Trans Ocean Heavy Equipment : Cart Order';
$email->Body      = $content;
$email->IsHTML(true);
$email->AddAddress( $WEB_MASTER );
$email->AddAddress( $_POST[Email] );
if ( $email->send() ){

        echo "success";
}
else{
        echo "555 " .$email->ErrorInfo;

}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried port 587?  This is the TLS port for gmail according to examples.

Comment: yes I did, but the problem stays the same

Comment: You're using an old version of PHPMailer. [Get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), base your code on the examples provided with it, and read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Comment: what version should  I download?